# Groupby from long data format to avoid inflated counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df in long format

```
df

comment         review     category    date           book        score
 book was ok   positive    children   2010-01-19    hp          0.5
 book was ok   positive    fiction    2010-01-19    hp          0.5
 book was ok   positive    ebook      2010-01-19    hp          0.5
 book was bad  negative   children   2010-01-19     austen      0.9
 book was bad  negative   fiction    2010-01-19     austen      0.9
```

Is there  a way to generate summary statistics by date and book, given df is in long format?

```
df1
date           book      positive_share_of_reviews_per_date_book  rolling_avg_of_preceding_column_per_book
2010-01-19   austen       
2010-01-19   hp         
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'book'])['score'].agg(['size', 'mean'])
```

put the columns you want to groupby in the first list, the variables you are interested in in the second, and finally the metrics with .agg()

Comment: How do I avoid counting duplicate books when calculating the size because its long format.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've understood what you were looking to do. It sounds like you want to get all of the unique date-book combinations first which you could perhaps do as given above (the multiindex would be this) then create new columns for your calculations, or create a function which isolates each book then performs operations on the sub-dataframe to get the values you need. if you can give a bit more detail on the expected output to show what you need I can have a go.